# Django project giving 500 internal server error on production server

Tags: python, django

I am working on django project, I have created project on production server, and configured it with mod_wsgi as per official documentation, but when i am trying to access it on url it give me 500 internal server error, I have not changed debug mode to false yet.

[image]

I have configured httpd.conf file like this

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/onpoint/public_html/project-name/project-name/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/onpoint/public_html/project-name

<Directory /home/onpoint/public_html/project-name/project-name>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
```

Installed mod_wsgi as well, But its giving me this error again and again.
Thanks

Comment: Check the error log of the HTTP server first. If you don't find any problems there, set [`ADMINS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-ADMINS) and check for error messages from django, next.

Comment: i am using centos vps and i searched on internet for http log files i got that on centos log files are in /var/log/httpd/error_log but when i searched for these directories in my centos server i did not get httpd directory under /var/log

Comment: Your `http.conf` or related files should also contain an `ErrorLog` directive pointing to the location of the error log file. If not, you certainly need one.

Comment: I checked in error log its giving me error :-  configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!:

Comment: I changed "Require all granted" to " Allow from all" also added "Order deny,allow" above it because my apache version is older than 2.4